# Iterator for each item in a 2D Python list and its immediate m by n neighbourhood

Tags: python, list, iterator

I need to generate an iterator which will iterate over a Python 2D array and yield each item and all the items around it in an MxN neighbourhood.

For instance, given a list of 0s and 1s in a checkerboard pattern, I need an iterator object that would yield a 3x3 neighbourhood such as:

```
[0,1,0],
[1,0,1],
[0,1,0]
```

N.B. The yield does not need to be another array, but it would be nice to be able to refer to neighbours with positions/indexes relative to the central item, or at least relative to each other.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: So far I have been trying to do it solely by index, i.e.

```
for x in range(len(S)):
    for y in range(len(S[0])):
        for i in range(-1,2):
            for j in range(-1,2):
                #access neighbour with S[x+i][y+j]
```

Comment: Show us the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
board = [
    [1,0,1,0,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1]
]

def clamp(minV,maxV,x):
    if x < minV:
        return minV 
    elif x > maxV:
        return maxV
    else:
        return x

def getNeighbour(grid,startx,starty,radius):
    width = len(grid[starty])
    height = len(grid)
    neighbourhood = []
    for y in range(clamp(0,height,starty-radius),clamp(0,height,starty+radius)+1):
        row = []
        for x in range(clamp(0,width,startx-radius),clamp(0,width,startx+radius)+1):
            if x != startx or (x==startx and  y != starty):
                row.append(grid[y][x])
        neighbourhood.append(row)
    return neighbourhood
```

Examples:

```
>>> pprint(getNeighbour(board, 0, 0, 1))
[0]
[1, 0] (expected)
>>> pprint(getNeighbour(board, 2, 2, 1))
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 1, 0] (expected)
>>>
```

---

Addressing the performance aspect with a list like:

```
board = [[1,0]*2000]*1000
```

The run time is essentially the same as if the board were 10x10

Comment: Thanks. Just a quick question. If I needed to get the neighbour for each item on a 4000x2000 'board', is this an efficient way of doing so?

Comment: I would say so yes, it doesn't examine the whole board at all, only the cells around it.

Comment: @user2515310 if works by moving out `radius` amount in each direction, it doesn't iterate over the board. If this answered your question you should consider accepting it.

Comment: The run time being essentially the same regardless of the board size says nothing about whether the performance is good or bad. In other words it be slow in any case. Also, `getNeighbour()` is not an iterator, although returns something that is iterable.

Comment: Yes, but the above isn't slow (at least in most domains)

Comment: "isn't slow" as compared to what? Otherwise that's a baseless assertion. Frankly it looks relatively slow with all the function calls it makes during the process of building the list returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can often get fast access of 2 dimensional array by storing the elements in a one dimensional list and computing offset bases on the logical width and height of array. It can often simplify calculations and bounds-checking, which only have to deal with one dimension internally.

```
class Board(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.size = width*height
        self.board = [i%2 for i in xrange(self.size)] # checkerboard init

    def __getitem__(coords):
        """ get board[x, y] """
        offset = coords[1]*self.width + coords[0]
        return self.board[offset]

    def __setitem__(coords, value):
        """ set board[x, y] = value """
        offset = coords[1]*self.width + coords[0]
        self.board[offset] = value

    def __str__(self):
        lines = []
        for y in xrange(self.height):
            offset = y*self.width
            row = self.board[offset:offset+self.width]
            lines.append(','.join(str(v) for v in row))
        return ',\n'.join(lines)

    def neighbourhood(self, x, y):
        position = y*self.width + x
        for offset in [
            position-self.width-1, position-self.width, position-self.width+1,
            position-1,                                 position+1,
            position+self.width-1, position+self.width, position+self.width+1]:
            if -1 < offset < self.size:
                yield self.board[offset]

board = Board(5, 5)
print board
print
print [value for value in board.neighbourhood(0, 0)]
print [value for value in board.neighbourhood(2, 2)]
```

Output:

```
0,1,0,1,0,
1,0,1,0,1,
0,1,0,1,0,
1,0,1,0,1,
0,1,0,1,0

[1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```